# Automatic Method Invocation Prior to Any Other Method Call

Tags: c#, inheritance, n-tier-architecture

I have a large number of classes inheriting from a large number of interfaces. The interfaces that these classes are implementing do not share any common methods, but they all share a common first step. An illustration of this is:

Class A looks like this:

```
class A : InterfaceA
{

    GetFoo(Database db)
    {
       PerformSetup(db); // This is the common first step.

       // Do foo things
    }
}
```

Class B might look something like this:

```
class B : InterfaceB
{
    GetBar(Database db)
    {
        PerformSetup(db); // This is the common first step.

        // Do bar things
    }
}
```

Now obviously I could just create a base class with a method PerformSetup and have all of these methods call that. But my issue is that there are *very* many methods, and that call to PerformSetup() needs to be in all of them, but it is not yet in any of them.

So I could certainly just copy-paste that setup code to the beginning of every single method, but in the interest of DRY and my own time, I was wondering if there was some way I could ensure this method would be automatically called before any (public-only if possible) method call? Could I make use of events somehow? Keep in mind again that no class shares a common interface, and that many of these interface methods have parameters in addition to the Database parameter, but they all do have the database parameter.

This probably a bit fantastical but I am always curious to see what crazy contraptions people are able to rig up in C#.

Comment: Check out method interception with IoC frameworks to run code before interface methods - I think it is somewhat different from what you want to achieve - so comment... I.e. [Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg535676.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible answers:

1. Use [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/aspects/method-decorator). It costs, but I guess it works.
2. You could use reflection to call the `PerformSetup` method before you call your methods

Basically you can make a base class with the following

```
class Base
{
    public void InvokeMethodWithSetup(string method, Database db, params object[] args)
    {
        PerformSetup(db);
        var method = this.GetType().GetMethod(method);
        method.Invoke(this, args);   
    }

    public void PerformSetup(Database db)
    {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

This unfortunately means going to everywhere one of your methods is called to replace the invocation code, so I don't know if that makes it much easier, but at least it saves you having to modify all the methods.